# slaves get a connection timed out with hdfs

Tags: amazon-ec2, cluster, hadoop

I have 3 node instances -

```
master, slave1 and slave2
```

SSHing between these nodes works fine.

Here is the processes that starts on each node when I say `./sbin/start-dfs.sh`

**master:**

```
SecondaryNameNode
Jps
NameNode
DataNode
```

**slave1:**

```
Jps
DataNode
```

**slave2:**

```
Jps
DataNode
```

***But when I try to access hdfs from slave nodes, I get a `connection timed out`.***

Also when I check the `hdfs dfsadmin -report`, I only see one datanode(on master's localhost) as part of hdfs.

```
Datanodes available: 1 (1 total, 0 dead)

Live datanodes:
Name: 127.0.0.1:50010 (localhost)
Hostname: master
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 8309932032 (7.74 GB)
DFS Used: 24576 (24 KB)
Non DFS Used: 2309738496 (2.15 GB)
DFS Remaining: 6000168960 (5.59 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 72.20%
```

Here is my /etc/hosts file mapping on all the three nodes.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
<ip of master> master
<ip of slave1> slave1
<ip of slave2> slave2
```

Here is my $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/slaves file on the master

```
localhost
slave1
slave2
```

In short, datanodes on slaves are unable to connect with hdfs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set fs.default.name correctly on all three nodes in conf/core-site.xml?

Comment: @VictorJerlin I have set fs.default.name as hdfs://master:9000 in all the 3 nodes.

Comment: Just noticed the part about connection timing out.  If you can't telnet to port 9000 on the master from the slaves(and the error is connection timed out), then it's most likely a firewall issue.  Check that the ec2 instances are in the same ec2 security group, and that there's no iptables firewall rules active blocking the connections.

Comment: They all belong to the same security group. Though, the rule is           SSH
TCP
22
0.0.0.0/0   Is this fine?

Comment: @VictorJerlin The answer about the firewall is right. It works when I opened all incoming traffic. Please post your answer so that I would accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't telnet to port 9000 on the master from the slaves(and the error is connection timed out), then it's most likely a firewall issue.

Check that the ec2 instances are in the same ec2 security group, and that there's no iptables firewall rules active blocking the connections(you can check this by running iptables -vnxL).